# Activity transition animation on root layout is executing on every EditText click

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I am applying reveal effect on activity transition, when the startActivity is called the activity displayed through reveal effect. Activity is register activity which contains 3 editText, a imageView and a button to take image.

"**The problem is whenever I select or click on editText the reveal effect animation is applying.**"

The animation is applied on root layout and animation is started in OnCreate method, I also tried applying animation through other lifecycle methods like onStart and onResume methods but it is working.

Answer is accepted with an pleasure.
Here is the snapshot of code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_contact);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_name_id);
    Mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_mobile_id);
    Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_email_id);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.set_image);

    LinearLayout rootview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootview);

    rootview.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, 
        int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) 
        {

            float finalRadius=
            (float)Math.hypot(v.getWidth(),v.getHeight());
            int cx1 = (v.getLeft() + v.getRight()) / 2;
            int cy1 = (v.getTop() + v.getBottom()) / 2;
            Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(v, 
            cx1, cy1, 0, finalRadius);
            anim.setDuration(1000);
            anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            anim.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait using a globalLayoutListener:

```
final LinearLayout rootview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootview);
rootview .getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    rootview .getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    // remove listener
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        //noinspection deprecation
        imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    } else {
        imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }

    float finalRadius=
    (float)Math.hypot(rootview.getWidth(),rootview.getHeight());
    int cx1 = (rootview.getLeft() + rootview.getRight()) / 2;
    int cy1 = (rootview.getTop() + rootview.getBottom()) / 2;
    Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(v, 
    cx1, cy1, 0, finalRadius);
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    anim.start();
}
});
```

You might not need the check for the old version id you do not support lower than JELLY_BEAN

Comment: I am applying listener for root layout not for image view, Or U mean I have to replace **imageView** of your code to **rootView**......?????. I am not getting explain Please.

Comment: the listener can be added to any view, it will simply be called once, when the layout is complete

Comment: Hi, I have a question, Below code ( **sarthak Gandhi**) also works fine. In these two answers, which one is efficient....?

Comment: This one is better because it only gets called when the layout is done, the done below waits for an arbitrary timeout, so in the best case it waits too long, in the worst case, it does not wait long enough and does not work at all.

Comment: Tx for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that whenever you click on the image or the edit text the onLayoutChange method is being called. Just start your animation in onCreate rather than putting it in onLayoutChanged.

```
    root.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            float finalRadius =
                    (float) Math.hypot(root.getWidth(), root.getHeight());
            int cx1 = (root.getLeft() + root.getRight()) / 2;
            int cy1 = (root.getTop() + root.getBottom()) / 2;
            Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(root,
                    cx1, cy1, 0, finalRadius);
            anim.setDuration(1000);
            anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            anim.start();
        }
    });
```

Please try this.

Comment: I tired it but it is giving an Runtime Exception. **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot start this animator on a detached view!** on this this line **Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(v, cx1, cy1, 0, finalRadius);**

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...
    ...

    final LinearLayout rootview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootview);
    ViewTreeObserver observer = rootview.getViewTreeObserver();

    if (observer.isAlive()) {
        observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                showLayout(rootview)
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    rootview.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    rootview.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    ...
    ...
}

private void showLayout(@NonNull View v) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        circularReveal(v);
    } else {
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void circularReveal(@NonNull final View v) {
    float finalRadius = (float) Math.hypot(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
    int cx1 = (v.getLeft() + v.getRight()) / 2;
    int cy1 = (v.getTop() + v.getBottom()) / 2;
    Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(v, cx1, cy1, 0, finalRadius);
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    anim.start();
}
```

In xml parent layout put this `android:visibility="invisible"`